# My Gitorious doesn't create the repositories!

Tags: git, gitorious

I've just installed gitorious here, but I'm having problems creating new repositories.
I configured it to create them in the /home/git/ directory,  and the it's already 777.
When I create a new repository, it goes to "This repository is being created,
it will be ready pretty soon…" and keep showing this forever.

I started the git-daemon from the scripts, the log:

```
2009-06-09 15:19:27 [31837] Received TERM, exiting..
2009-06-09 15:19:40 [32467] Listening on 0.0.0.0:9418...
```

Any idea what could be happening? Or where I could look for more info

Answer (score 16):

It's almost two years later, but.. ya, you need to run the poller. To test this, as the git user in the gitorious directory try running

```
script/poller run
```

This will run the poller synchronously. It will keep running until you hit control-C. If this starts your repositories being created etc, then you need to look into getting the file `/etc/init.d/git-poller` set up and running at boot time.

Hoping this helps someone else out there who runs into this.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot. I didn't realise that my poller service was down for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: This is almost another two years later... does anyone know how to solve this issue with gitorious v >= 3?

Answer (score 4):

you need to start the poller (script/poller and run an STOMP compatible queue server, such as activemq), please consult the gitorious mailinglist and/or docs, as I only came across this thread by pure accident and likely wont again

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you have a firewall active, preventing you to contact the port 9418.  Since you mention `/home/git`, I am assuming you run git on Linux.  It seems customary these days for Linux distributions to come with firewalls active and preconfigured.

So, retry either with the firewall down, or if you are paranoid, with the firewall pierced at port 9148.  Look for the messages from the git daemon in the logs.

If it doesn't work, come back with more info.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in your admin go to: admin/repositories (there is no link to it as far as I am aware)

Follow the instructions.